# Problems updating a record in a table in ado.net

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

Can anyone help me with this code. I am trying to update a record but I get this error `The DataAdapter.SelectCommand property needs to be initialized.` in this line `data_adapter.UpdateCommand = builder.GetUpdateCommand();` I can't figure it out how to fix it.

```
public partial class AirlineReservation : Form
    {
        public SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(local); Initial Catalog=Airline_Reservation; Integrated Security=SSPI");
        public SqlDataAdapter data_adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        public DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        public DataGridView parentDataGridView = new DataGridView();
        public BindingSource parentBindingSource = new BindingSource();
        public DataGridView childDataGridView = new DataGridView();
        public BindingSource childBindingSource = new BindingSource();

        SqlCommand select_planes = new SqlCommand();
        SqlCommand select_airlines = new SqlCommand();
        public SqlCommandBuilder builder;

        public DataRelation rel;

        public AirlineReservation()
        {
            InitializeComponent();           
        }

        private void getData()
        {
            SqlDataAdapter parentDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Airline", connection);
            parentDataAdapter.Fill(ds, "Airline");
            SqlDataAdapter childDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Plane", connection);
            childDataAdapter.Fill(ds, "Plane");

            DataColumn parentColumn = ds.Tables["Airline"].Columns["airline_id"];
            DataColumn childColumn = ds.Tables["Plane"].Columns["airline_id"];

            rel = new DataRelation("PlaneAirline", parentColumn, childColumn);
            ds.Relations.Add(rel);

            parentBindingSource.DataSource = ds;
            parentBindingSource.DataMember = "Airline";
            childBindingSource.DataSource = parentBindingSource;
            childBindingSource.DataMember = "PlaneAirline";   
        }

        private void AirlineReservation_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            parentDataGridView.DataSource = parentBindingSource;
            childDataGridView.DataSource = childBindingSource;
            getData();  
        }

        private void dg_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

            DataView dv = new DataView(ds.Tables["Plane"], "airline_id = " + dg.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value, "", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
            dg2.DataSource = dv;
        }

        private void display_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dg.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        }

        private void dg2_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGridViewRow row = dg2.Rows[e.RowIndex];
            aidbox.Text = row.Cells["airline_id"].Value.ToString();
            pid_box.Text = row.Cells["plane_id"].Value.ToString();
            name_box.Text = row.Cells["name"].Value.ToString();
            model_box.Text = row.Cells["model"].Value.ToString();
            fc_box.Text = row.Cells["f_seats"].Value.ToString();
            sc_box.Text = row.Cells["s_seats"].Value.ToString();
            bs_box.Text = row.Cells["b_seats"].Value.ToString();
            weight_box.Text = row.Cells["p_weight"].Value.ToString();

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataRow[] row_update = ds.Tables["Plane"].Select("airline_id = " + aidbox.Text);
            try
            {
                var row = row_update[0];
                row["airline_id"] = int.Parse(aidbox.Text);
                row["plane_id"] = int.Parse(pid_box.Text);
                row["name"] = name_box.Text;
                row["model"] = model_box.Text;
                row["f_seats"] = int.Parse(fc_box.Text);
                row["s_seats"] = int.Parse(sc_box.Text);
                row["b_seats"] = int.Parse(bs_box.Text);
                row["p_weight"] = float.Parse(weight_box.Text);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }

            try
                {
                    builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(data_adapter);
                    data_adapter.UpdateCommand = builder.GetUpdateCommand();

                    data_adapter.Update(ds, "Plane");

                }
                catch (SqlException ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not initialized `data_adapter` object properly.

In this line you have just created a object of Data Adapter

```
public SqlDataAdapter data_adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
```

you need to specify select command in it.

```
public SqlDataAdapter data_adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
data_adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("Select Query", connection);
```

or specify at declaration.

```
public SqlDataAdapter data_adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Query", connection);
```

**Suggested code**

```
//Create this object at class level
public partial class AirlineReservation
{
    SqlDataAdapter childDataAdapter;
...
...

 private void getData()
 {
     use it like this in getData() function
     childDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Plane", connection);
     ...
     ...


private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataRow[] row_update = ds.Tables["Plane"].Select("airline_id = " + aidbox.Text);
    try
    {
        var row = row_update[0];
        row["airline_id"] = int.Parse(aidbox.Text);
        row["plane_id"] = int.Parse(pid_box.Text);
        row["name"] = name_box.Text;
        row["model"] = model_box.Text;
        row["f_seats"] = int.Parse(fc_box.Text);
        row["s_seats"] = int.Parse(sc_box.Text);
        row["b_seats"] = int.Parse(bs_box.Text);
        row["p_weight"] = float.Parse(weight_box.Text);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }

    try
        {
            builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(childDataAdapter);
                    //This line is not required
            //data_adapter.UpdateCommand = builder.GetUpdateCommand();
                    ds.EndInit();
            childDataAdapter.Update(ds, "Plane");

        }
        catch (SqlException ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }
    }

}
```

Comment: I wrote like this "public SqlDataAdapter data_adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("Plane", ConnectionState);"  Plane is the table I want to be updated. But I get some errors like : Error 4 Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Data.ConnectionState' to 'string' or Error 5 Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Data.ConnectionState' to 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection'

Comment: Change ConnectionState to connection.

Comment: declare `childDataAdapter` at class level where you have `data_adapter` object created and use it instead of data_adapter.

Comment: If I try to write connection in the declaration it doesn't recognize it. So I want to try the other option, to write data_adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("Plane", connection), but I don't know where to put it? Before the data_adapter.UpdateCommand?

Comment: Ok thanks that worked. Can you explain me please what does ds.EndInit() do?

Comment: when change any value in the datatable or dataset initially editing will be started. So, you must close the editing by using `EndEdit()` before updating data by dataadapter.  using `EndEdit()`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.endinit.aspx

Comment: Ok thanks. Can you please help me with this little problem. When I click the update button it updates the data that I want but what is strange is that the weight column changes also, even if I don't update it. For example if weight is 17.1 after I click the update button it becomes 17.1000003814697. I don't get it

Comment: don't use float datatype when value is decimal specific. use decimal datatype instead of float.